# interface two wire pH sensor with arduino

Tags: arduino, sensor, interface, bnc, ph

I have purchased this pH/EC sensor from https://www.cooking-hacks.com/ph-sensor however it does not have a BNC connector and just two wires, black and read. How could i interface this to an Arduino?

Has anyone got any experience with this?

Thanks

Comment: Find a datasheet, or use the notes at the end of that page to figure it out. It's probably a device that requires converting a voltage range measured at the red wire referenced to the black wire. It also needs to be calibrated to known good acid, neutral, and base solutions, or your readings are meaningless. Otherwise, this question is too broad.

Comment: there is no data sheet.. is the problem

Comment: "Find a datasheet, or use the notes at the end of that page ..." If you can find out the part inside the plastic you might find something. Or piece together a story using the app notes provided. Unfortunately, this SE is not really a design or "help me figure out this part" service.

Comment: Two links got me to: http://www.libelium.com/development/waspmote/documentation/smart-water-board-technical-guide/ Search for pH in that document. Example code for their platform is there. I'm sure there is a lib for Arduino somewhere. Maybe try the Arduino SE once you have a handle on the basics?

Comment: In the hopes you might still be listening to these updates, I ran across this which might be apropos: https://hackaday.com/2016/03/18/beyond-measure-instrumentation-amplifiers/

Answer (score 2):

Raw (without circuitry) pH electrodes have a rather high level bi-polar voltage output (hundreds of mV) but extremely high impedance (250M in the case of the one you referenced). You will need an amplifier with very low input bias current that amplifies and shifts the signal into the Arduino ADC range. You cannot connect the probe directly and expect it to do anything useful.

Most raw electrode pH probes are similar in output (0mV at 7pH and about -59.2mV/pH slope at 25°C) and are easily calibrated with buffer solutions so I don't share the pessimism of my learned colleagues.

Just look up some amplifier circuits aimed at pH probes and come back if or when you have any issues or questions about what you find.

For best accuracy, measure the temperature of the solution as well and adjust the -59.2mV/pH by about -0.2mV/°C difference from 25°C (the slope will be more like -61.2 mV/pH at 35°C). Obviously the effect of the slope tempco is much less if your solution is close to neutral pH.

Or go buy a product that performs the above mentioned function and provides a high level buffered signal related to pH.

Comment: I think this particular device already combines an amp, the pH sensor, and a temperature sensor so the right sort of hardware can just read it and then check the temp offset from the calibrated values.

Comment: The data you linked says 250M\$\Omega\$, which implies it's a raw sensor. If what you think is true you'll need to find the datasheet for the particular device and find what power it requires and what output voltage or current it provides and adapt to that.

Comment: I'm just going on what the OP provided via that link. The device is a "combination" device that is temperature calibrated, and reading from it you can read the temp at the same time to get the offset. The amp might be on the board it plugs into, of course. There is no datasheet; it seems to be a hobbyist device for specific device markets.